# Any workaround for extreme typing latency using ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

We are close to uninstall JetBrains ReSharper on all DEV machines. In many cases, it slows typing so down that it's impossible to code.

We also get a number of notifications from VStudio blaming ReSharper extension. JetBrains support blames VStudio instead.

Who knows the truth? What exactly affects the typing speed? *ReSharper settings, number of projects in VStudio solution, file length, regions tags, comments, number of classes, CPU speed, etc.*

We keep "Solution wide analysis" turned off and we are using the latest version of VStudio (2019) and of ReSharper (2019), of course.

We also disabled all these ReSharper options without resolving the issue:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: In this order, I would suggest: Update Resharper, update Visual Studio, better dev machine, turn off global code analysis, uninstall Resharper.

Comment: Xeon 6 cores (12 logical CPUs) based DELL machines with 32GB of RAM and SSD hard drive.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html

Comment: How big a solution do you have?

Comment: @Lasse: 2400 *.cs files in less than 20 C# projects.

Comment: There's something seriously wrong with your setup if 20 projects is grinding those machines to a halt. Overactive virus scanner perhaps?

Comment: No, we don't use any antivirus.

Comment: Perhaps you have a virus then!

Comment: You said you disabled them... are the snails still there?

Comment: Have you tried to send timeline performance snapshots to JetBrains for investigation?
Also you can try to disable option "show unused non-private type members when solution-wide analysis is off" in "ReSharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Settings"

Comment: @Ivan: Yes, they blame VStudio and its memory limited by x86 bitness...